# Связь между Android устройством и компьютером через интернет

Tags: android

Люди, подскажите, пожалуйста, как осуществить связь через Интернет между Android-смартфоном и ПК и передавать между ними данные.

P.S. В проекте удаленное управление компьютером, но вот как осуществить саму связь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала пишите сервер на чем угодно для компьютера, который должен будет открывать порт и ждать команды. Потом нужно будет сделать клиент который для андроида, который будет открывать сокет, отсылать команды и получать ответ от сервера о том как обстоит делос с поставленной задачей.

Погулите на тему клиент-серверных приложений, в частности это хорошо видно на примере реализации чата.

Answer (score 0):

Сам никогда не делал, но как-то ставил на VirtualBox Android_x86 по этой [статье](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/130201/)

Там нужно было Android_x86 связывать с Eclipse по средством сети таким образом:

```
./adb connect 192.168.56.101
```

Смотри раздел "Соединение виртуальной машины Android, AVD и Eclipse"

Comment: А как быть со смартфоном и подключением к ПК через интернет? Мне бы хотя бы простенькую программку для отправки какого-либо сообщения туда и обратно =)